# How to determine programmatically the current active profiles in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

In the Quarkus [Application Configuration Guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/application-configuration-guide) it mentions how to configure an app with profiles (eg. `%dev.quarkus.http.port=8181`).

But is there a way to access a Profile (or Environment) API so I can log the active profiles ? For example something like Spring:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationLifeCycle {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ApplicationLifeCycle");

    @Inject Environment env;

    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {
        LOGGER.info("The application is starting with profiles " + env.getActiveProfiles());
    }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

ProfileManager.getActiveProfile()?

Comment: Was just about to write that :)

Comment: Best accept the answer @agoncal if the answer works for you to make it easy for future readers to know that it works without having to read through the comments

Comment: I can't understant why [quarkus docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/config#configuration-profiles) doesn't include a so simple explanation like that. Thank's a lot @Romain!

Comment: Unfortunately, `ProfileManager.getActiveProfile()` is deprecated (as of 2.16.2.Final, & probably earlier), so we're back to square one again. =(

Answer (score 11):

The method `ProfileManager.getActiveProfile()` has been deprecated. You should use: `ConfigUtils.getProfiles()` instead.

Method:

```
public static List<String> getProfiles() {
     return ConfigProvider.getConfig().unwrap(SmallRyeConfig.class).getProfiles();
}
```

PD: Tested on Quarkus `v2.16.1.Final`